# How can I get Bangladeshi taka symbol "tk" or Unicode Character " ৳ " in java

Tags: java, unicode, currency, symbols

I was doing like

```
tvCartTotalAmount.setText("tk "+String.format("%.2f",totalAmount)+"/-");
```

the output was

> tk 315/-

I want to show like

> ৳ 315/-

How can I do that?

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: You didn't explain the problem?

Comment: sorry. that was the answer that i want to share... thought some one might have needed the suggestion... my reputation gone below 15 ... sorry again

Comment: If your source code is UTF-8 encoded, you can just use the character directly: `System.out.println("৳");`

Comment: what is the keyboard shortcut for "৳" ? i have found Shift+B .. but it didn't work... can you please help with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use Bangladeshi taka symbol in **Java**

```
tvCartTotalAmount.setText("\u09F3"+" Data");
```

The symbol will look like this

> " ৳ "

This [link](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/09f3/index.htm) will help you further...